# Angular.js inject scope into config when using httpprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope, ngresource

I am trying to set up Angular.js to handle ivalid post data. Originally, I was handling it with the promise object on each request but since it is the same code each time, I was hoping to do it in the app config similar to how I am handling the 401 response code to redirect to the login page.

Here is my code:

```
app.config ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$scope', ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $scope) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push ($q) ->
    'responseError': (response) ->
      if response.status is 401
        window.location = '/user/login'
      if response.status is 400
        $scope.errors = response.data.errors
      $q.reject(response)
  return
]
```

My problem is that I am getting the error "Error: [$injector:modulerr]" which occurs when I try to inject the scope. Is there another way I can use app config to return the errors to the controller to then display in my view?

I am using CoffeScript but can post javascript code if needed.